# Why conversion between default system datetime to PersianCalendar is not working?

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller, globalization

I have a dateTime stored in database using this line of code:

```
var now=DateTime.Now;
```

so after it stored, the data is like this in database and also after recalling the entity:

> 2019-01-26 17:27:46.297

when i try to convert it to another culture datetime using this method:

```
public static string ToPersianDate(this DateTime t)
    {
        var pc = new PersianCalendar();
       return $"{pc.GetYear(t)}/{pc.GetMonth(t)}/{pc.GetDayOfMonth(t)}";
    }
```

after using this method :

```
var persianDate=now.ToPersianDate();
```

I get this string as a result:

> 2019/01/26

But I expected to get this result:

> 1397/11/06

Comment: @ ZDaneshi, please provide a [Minimal, Complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, I could not reproduce your problem, it is working fine

Comment: @hessamhedieh I edited my example

Answer (score -1):

Here is a complete example that converts time to `PersianCalender`,

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    { 
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var date = DateTime.Now;
            var str = date.ToPersianDate();
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static class Extender
    {
        public static string ToPersianDate(this DateTime t)
        {
            var pc = new PersianCalendar();
            return $"{pc.GetYear(t)}/{pc.GetMonth(t)}/{pc.GetDayOfMonth(t)}";
        }
    }
}
```

your problem its not reproducible, code is attached for further reference